# How can I get to know which type JSON returns by JsonSerializer.Deserialize?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, system.text.json

Now I am using the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` from `System.Text.Json` to deserialize from string to model. However, there are two situations while I get JSON from the third-party API of remote server. When everything runs well, it will return the JSON including the chat message I need:

```
{
    "msg": "hello everyone!",
    "msgtype": "text"
}
```

When there is something wrong with the code, it will return the JSON including the error:

```
{
    "errorcode": "123",
    "errormsg": "Not such table \"aaa\""
}
```

I want to know which type of JSON returns every time, the message or the error above.

I consider using the `String.Contain("errorcode")` to get to know whether it returns the message JSON or the error JSON at the beginning.

However, the chat message is unpredictable that it even maybe contains the text "errorcode" in message JSON.

Here are the codes:

```
  public class msgModel
    {
        public string msg{ get; set; }
        public string msgtype{ get; set; }
    }
 public class errorModel
    {
        public string errorcode{ get; set; }
        public string errormsg{ get; set; }
    }
```

I always deserialize JSON like this:

```
string JSON="";//some JSON
JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JSON, typeof(msgModel));
```

I can only add a `try{}catch{}` around it to catch whether the JSON returns an error. I don't think it is the correct way to do it. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend integrating all properties into 1 object and checking for the "errorcode" being present.

```
public class MsgModel
{
    [JsonProperty("errormsg")]
    public string Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("errorcode")]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("msg")]
    public string msg { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("msgtype")]
    public int msgtype { get; set; }
}
```

Next, all you'd have to do is check `if object.errorcode.isNullorEmpty` and go from there.

[This is more robust](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/deserialize-different-json-object-same-class/)